# reporting services matrix row question

Tags: reporting-services, matrix

I have a report that i'm trying to display in a matrix.  The Row is grouped by a column called Category.  The column name is vcName.  The detail is vcTaskName.  The part that i can't seem to figure out is that only one row will show up even if there are multipal tasknames with that row value.

Try to give an example.

```
Category       vcTaskName        vcName
a              task1             dog
a              task2             dog
a              task3             cat
a              task4             bird
```

so with Category being the row, only task1 is showing up for dog, task 2 doesn't display.  for cat and bird task 3 and task 4 show up correctly.  None of these three have anything in the expression to limit it to first.

Anyway... i hope that is enough info to get started.
Thanks
Shannon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only display one value in a cell in a matrix - normally, this is some sort of aggregate value. In order to display multiple values, you need to have multiple cells - this means adding another group to either the rows or the columns.

Assuming that each task name is going to be different (as in the sample data), I suggest adding a new column to your query to hold the running count of vcTaskName within the Category and vcName - so your data would look like this:

```
Category       vcTaskName        vcName    TaskRunCount
a              task1             dog       1
a              task2             dog       2
a              task3             cat       1
a              task4             bird      1
```

and then add a second group to the Tablix on the TaskRunCount - this will ensure that task1 and task2 will appear on separate lines in the dog column.

Comment: Thanks for your response.. i was able to get a sql statement to work that delevered the data in this format and then the report part was as easy as you said.  Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

YOu will have to do a screen capture or print of the report and paste here, it appears you have placed the field in a grouping.  Wether there is an expression or not doesnt matter, once you place a field in a group reporting services assumes the function FIRST().